# How to control speed of DC Gearmotor with Varying Torque

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, motors, control-theory, electrical

I have a system where the torque is constantly changing, but I need the speed to remain at 9RPM. I have enough room for error where I can be between 8 and 10RPM. How can I achieve this? All I can find info on is SCR's, but that doesn't have a feedback controller so I don't understand how it would hold the speed at 9RPM as the torque varies.

Comment: SCRs on their own would not. SCRs are but one component of motor drivers for *some* types of motors and motors DC motors are not among them. Looking for things like SCRs when you need a motor driver is like looking at tires when you need a car. Look for motor drivers with speed control and feedback.

Comment: please provide a link to the motor datasheet

Comment: Yep, you need either built-in or external feedback to control the power feed to your motor.

Comment: https://www.grainger.com/product/DAYTON-DC-Gearmotor-90V-DC-6Z912 This is the motor I am using. I have also found a separate driver, would something like this work at regulating my speed?  https://www.grainger.com/product/DART-CONTROLS-DC-Speed-Control-SCR-6Z386

Comment: @DKNguyen what would you look for if you are searching for a DC motor driver with feedback control then? Everything I find for motor speed control is literally just a SCR or PWM "controller" which just lets you set the speed, but doesn't look like it is closed-loop. I could definitely be wrong but just wondering.

Comment: You don't want anything that has SCRs. Transistors is what you want but they are so ubiquitous they won't advertise as using transistors. 90V is a bit high for hobbiest motor controllers though. THis could get expensive.